# Boyer-Moore String Search algorithm starting alignments

Tags: java, c, algorithm

I'm not a professional programmer, so pls bear with me.
I'm looking around for reasons as to why the initial 'alignment' of haystack and needle should not be made at the first congruence of the needle's last character with the same one in the haystack, *but at the earliest* that being sought at needle.length()-1, rather than enforcing a comparison at 'haystack.needle.length()-1' and 'needle.length()-1'  ?

Example :-

haystack : actuateaaaaaat

needle   :   descant

Above, everything before the final 't' in haystack can be completely ignored, in terms of shifts and comparisons theretofore.

Comment: How do you find that point in the haystack without looking at all the preceding characters?

Answer (score 3):

If you were to try to find the first `t` in the haystack (starting at the seventh character), you would have to look at every character in the haystack until the end.

Boyer Moore finds the position with many fewer comparisons. For example, after comparing `t` with `e`, it can move forward five characters. So the next comparison will be between the `t` and the second last `a`, and that will lead to a displacement of two. So the correct alignment is found after just two comparisons instead of seven.

Comment: Yes, I fully understand your point of course. I'm seeing the irony however that there is no real way to take advantage of a self-evident possibility of this kind - which the human eye can see and logic support, but which can't be implemented in code effectively. In tests nevertheless, timings for the algorithm I've outlined are better in certain cases than the B-M equivalent.

Comment: @bjwg: That's highly dependent on how you code the two possibilities. But on the whole, a well-written Boyer-Moore is a big win. (I'm not sure that its really a case of "irony", but it is certainly true that complex parallel processing systems like human vision can sometimes outperform a computer. On the other, human vision suffers from optical illusions so all is not necessarily what it seems.

Comment: <<you would have to look at every character in the haystack until the end.>>. Right, although the search space decreases of course as the needle moves along the haystack. I'd imagine that the relative 'rarity' of the needle's character in the overall alphabet will also impact performance, so searching for an 'e' would be more time-consuming than looking for a 'z'.